# Get the line number on which there is an error in JSON schema definition

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is it possible to get the line number on which there is an error while validation the schema definition
for example, if we have a schema and we make a typo like "objects" in type property value (the correct one is "object") and it will tell us that there is an error on line number "20"

Comment: For reference, already answered: https://github.com/json-schema-org/community/discussions/53

Comment: This is more a question of JSON Pointer to line number, which is not conveyed well here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible, unless your implementation has knowledge of the original JSON document itself before it was inflated into whatever native data structure the implementation is using.

To my knowledge there are no JSON decoders that provide a decoded data structure that is decorated with line numbers from the original document (but I'd love to hear about any that exist).

However, errors *do* contain the path information to the property or item that contains the error. This is described here in the spec: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.12.3